# how to remove 0 coefficient in objective function when using Cplex with Python?

Tags: python, cplex

I am using Cplex in Python to solve mathematical programming problem.

To make sure the code I wrote is correct, I used the code

```
c.write("form2.lp")
```

In my problem I have a lot of variables with zero coefficients in the objective function and those variables are appeared in objective function.

Like "`+ 0 m_1_2_1`"  for example. Because of these terms, it is difficult to determine if my formulation is correct. Is there a way to delete terms with zero coefficients?

Comment: I tried to export a very simple OPL model (maximize a; subject to { a <=b; a <= 6 }) from CPLEX IDE and I did not see any zero coefficients (for b) in resulting LP file (...Maximize
 obj: a Subject To...). I assume, Python should behave the same. Do you set zeroes in your model or are there some unused variables?

Comment: oh! I commented out some of my constrains to check easily and that is the  reason. Thank you